# App doesn't remember my preferences or information when restored

Tags: icloud, restore, whatsapp.app

My old iPhone got replaced by Apple as it was faulty. Now I did my iCloud restore on my new iPhone 6, but when I open WhatsApp or Viber and even the any of app doesn't remember my number or information of any sort, e.g on WhatsApp it is asking me for my number and I sort of can't provide it, as I am outside the country for a few months and don't have my SIM card with me, which was registered to that. I am totally blocked out. Should i making a appointment with apple or is it something wrong with my backup, as in past i was able to recover my icloud data and app stored information without re-entering it again,

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: It's your phone number WhatsApp is asking for. Why can't you enter that?

Comment: @patrix That number is back in my home country as like i said i am visiting other country and will be here for few months.

Comment: And you don't know the number?

Comment: @patrix I know that number and that sim is in other country, so even I get text on that number I cannot access.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're outside the country where the phone carrier is originally provided, you still can provide your number to WhatsApp. After providing your number, you'll receive a text from WhatsApp that contains the activation code. Then, enter the activation code in WhatsApp to re-activate it.